# How do I create an Access query to get multiple row;, one row for each column in a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, multirow

I looked here for a solution, but didn't find anything similar.

Here is my Discounts table:

| ID | SilverVAR | GoldVAR | PlatinumVAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA2R | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| GB34 | 22 | 25 | 45 |
| HT4R | 25 | 28 | 50 |

I need output that looks like this:

| ID | PartnerType | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA2R | SilverVAR | 20 |
| CA2R | GoldVAR | 30 |
| CA2R | PlatinumVAR | 40 |
| GB34 | SilverVAR | 22 |
| GB34 | GoldVAR | 25 |
| GB34 | PlatinumVAR | 45 |
| HT4R | SilverVAR | 25 |
| HT4R | GoldVAR | 28 |
| HR4R | PlatinumVAR | 50 |

Is this possible? How do I go about it?

I tried CrossTab but that doesn't seem to be the solution especially if there are more partner type columns across the Discounts table.

Comment: I think writing a VBA module to build the SQL dynamically is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will consider this. It may be possible to use VBA to build the SQL using the SQL hints provided below by user "June7".

Comment: Yes, VBA can open recordset of table, loop through fields, build UNION SQL statement and modify saved query object with DAO QueryDefs OR loop records and fields and save data in a 'temp' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example VBA code you can adapt:

```
Public Sub MakeNewQry()
    Const CrossTabQryName As String = "qryCrossTab"
    Dim db As Database, fld As Field, strSQL As String
    
    With CurrentDb
        strSQL = ""
        For Each fld In .TableDefs("Discounts").Fields
           If fld.Name Like "?*VAR" Then
             strSQL = IIf(strSQL = "", "", strSQL & vbCrLf & "UNION ALL ") & _
                    "select ID, '" & fld.Name & "' as PartnerType, " & fld.Name & " as Discount from Discounts "
           End If
        Next fld
        Dim qd As QueryDef
        Set qd = New QueryDef
        qd.Name = CrossTabQryName
        qd.sql = strSQL
        
        '---Delete the old query
        On Error Resume Next
        .QueryDefs().Delete (CrossTabQryName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .QueryDefs().Append qd
        set qd=nothing
    End With
    
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I'm pretty good with VBA for Excel, I don't have a lot of experience with VBA for Access, so this is a big help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

A CROSSTAB is definitely not appropriate. What you want is the opposite (UNPIVOT).

A UNION query can rearrange fields to normalized structure. There is no designer for UNION, must build in SQLView. There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines. First SELECT determines field names.

```
SELECT ID, "Silver" AS PartnerType, SilverVAR AS Discount FROM Discounts
UNION SELECT ID, "Gold", GoldVAR FROM Discounts
UNION SELECT ID, "Platinum", PlatinumVAR FROM Discounts;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Hope so. If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.